# How to get month in number from date in "JAN-2014" format?

Tags: php, jquery, date, format

Actually, i am using jquery datepicker and getting month in "MONTH-YEAR" format?
how i can get month number form this format in PHP or JAVASCRIPT?

js code:

```
  $("#date1_live").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
                        showAnim:'slideDown',
                        dateFormat:'M yy'
        });
```

html text field:

```
<input type="text" name="reportMonth" id="date1_live" required Placeholder="Select Start Date" >
```

Comment: Please provide some examples to what you get and what you want to achieve.

Comment: jquery datepicker text field output me date in month-year format. e.g when i select any date from july month it returns me jul-2014. so, i need month in number from this date! how can i do this?

Comment: share some relevant code that you have tried (it would be better if you can share jsfiddle), so that we can help you.

Comment: jQuery's datepicker will return a date object if used correctly, so you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using php try like this

```
$month = 'JAN-2014';
echo date('m', strtotime($month));
```

Comment: if this answer is usefull to you means please upvote and choose this as answer

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following documentation.

[jQuery UI Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

> The format for parsed and displayed dates. For a full list of the
>   possible formats see the formatDate function.
>   **Code examples:**
>   Initialize the datepicker with the dateFormat option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 alert($("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-yy" }).val());
```

or  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BUE8W/1/)

```
         {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showAnim:'slideDown',
            dateFormat:"mm-yy"
       }
```